# create a cmd shortcut which opens url in chrome, firefox and IE simultaneously

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

Well everyone aware about launching specific browser with some url.
What if you want to launch multiple browser simultaneously at same time with random url??
Looking for some command line shortcut which launches chrome, firefox and IE simultaneously with specific address. Keep in mind address will not be the same every time. I would like to have control over address to launch all browser simultaneously.

i.e `http://localhost:8080` should be launched in chrome, IE and firefox at same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET MyUrl=https://www.google.com

START iexplore.exe %MyUrl%
START "" [...]\chrome.exe %MyUrl%
START "" [...]\firefox.exe %MyUrl%
```

replace [...] with your browser's path. IE doesn't need it.

As per David's comment:
the first parameter to [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) (before the program name) is the title. 
It must be in quotes, but it may be null (i.e., the empty string `""`). 
In theory, the title is optional,
but if your program's path includes space(s),
then you must put that in quotes,
and then you must include a title
so `start` can tell that the program pathname isn't the title.

Comment: It never opens in firefox although am giving correct path. it opens same url twice in chrome. FYI chrome is my default browser. even when I run this in cmd `START "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" http://www.google.com` it launches in chrome.

Comment: @ankitd Use `START "" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" http://www.google.com` - the first parameter to [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) is the title ... "Always include a TITLE this can be a simple string like "My Script" or just a pair of empty quotes ""
According to the Microsoft documentation, the title is optional, but depending on the other options chosen you can have problems if it is omitted."

Comment: @ankitd If you omit the "" (title) then " ...firefox..." is the title and the url is launched in the default browser (chrome in your case).

Comment: @DavidPostill thnx a lot...  its working like champ.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command at the command prompt:

```
start http://www.google.com
```

That will open google using the default browser in your computer.

If you want to open the URL using Chrome, type:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "http://www.google.com"
```

Comment: before posting any answer read the question carefully. the que is to open all 3 at same time.